# How to extract a subdir with all it's subsequent files using zipfile

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

Yes, I have read the other posts on this subject, but I am running into a weird problem:

When I extract a certain item from the `namelist`, it only gives me an empty folder, not the actual files inside.

My zip file has the following hierarchy:

myzip.zip -> FolderA -> FolderB -> FolderC -> FolderIWantA, FolderIWantB, ... FolderIWantN.

So there are a lot of preceeding folders I do not wish to extract. I know how to identify the ones I want from the namelist:

```py
import os
import sys
import zipfile

try:
    zip_file_path = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    sys.exit('No zip file provided.')

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path)

for i,file in enumerate(archive.namelist()):
    if os.path.basename(file[:-1]).startswith('ABC-'): # identify relevant folders
        old_name = os.path.basename(file[:-1])
        new_name = 'new_%d'%i # Create a new name
        
        archive.extract(file, new_name)
```

This does extract the folders I want, however the extracted folders are empty for some reason. And not just that: When I extract the new folders, they contain the preceeding folders A,B and C for some reason.

I do not know why it does that...
Here's a test zip for your convenience:

```py
import os
import shutil

prefolders = r'testzip\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC'

try:
    os.makedirs(prefolders)
except FileExistsError:
    pass


for i in 'ABC':
    try:
        new_folder = 'ABC-Folder%s'%i
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(prefolders,new_folder))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass

    for j in range(2):
        file_path = os.path.join(prefolders,new_folder,'somefile%s.txt'%j)
        with open(file_path,'w'): pass

shutil.make_archive('testzip', 'zip', 'testzip')
shutil.rmtree('testzip')
```

I thought this would take like 10 minutes and I am losing my mind over this...

Comment: Good job providing a test case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `basename()` to start with `ABC-`, which means you never find *files* that don't start with that. The files in your example start with `somefile`. `extract()` will only extract the one thing that is named. In your case, all of the things that start with `ABC-` are directories.

To find the *files* that have a directory somewhere in their path that starts with `ABC-`, you could:

```py
    if os.path.basename(file) != '' and ('/ABC-' in os.path.dirname(file) or os.path.dirname(file).startswith('ABC-')):
```

(You may need to change the slash to a backslash on your system.)

This will still extract the file and all of the parent directories as named in `file`. If you want just the file by itself in `new_n`, then you will need to use `read()` on the entry, and then write the data to the desired destination file.

Comment: is there really no method/function built into zipfile to extract a certain item from the namelist recursively? Also I do not understand why zipfile insists on always return posix paths. I feel like there has to be a more convenient lib to work with when working with zipfile...

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: The zip file format mandates the use of forward slashes for path separators.